# Mockito @Mock does not inject named mocks correctly using constructor injection

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to use @Mock to inject two different objects into my class under test. I need them to be two different objects so that I can use `when` on each one to produce different results. Everything I've searched on SO points toward this working, but when running the test below - both objects are the same mock.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import com.ihm.pp.test.UnitTest;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

/**
 * @author Josh Johnston
 */
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConstructorInjectionBug {

  @Mock
  private IBroken aBroken;

  @Mock
  private IBroken bBroken;

  @InjectMocks
  private UsesBroken usesBroken;

  @Test
  public void testBrokenConstructorInjection() {

    when(bBroken.getNumber()).thenReturn(2);
    assertEquals(2, usesBroken.getbBroken().getNumber());

    when(aBroken.getNumber()).thenReturn(1);
    assertEquals(1, usesBroken.getaBroken().getNumber());
  }
}

interface IBroken {
  int getNumber();
}

class UsesBroken {

  private IBroken aBroken;
  private IBroken bBroken;

  public UsesBroken(IBroken aBroken, IBroken bBroken) {
    this.aBroken = aBroken;
    this.bBroken = bBroken;
  }

  public IBroken getaBroken() {
    return aBroken;
  }

  public IBroken getbBroken() {
    return bBroken;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
    Expected :1
    Actual   :2

at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
    at ConstructorInjectionBug.testBrokenConstructorInjection(ConstructorInjectionBug.java:37)
```

Comment: Does the same happen when you manually create the mocks and explicitly inject into the subject under test?

Comment: @Nkosi do you mean with `mock(IBroken.class)` and calling the constructor myself? No idea, but that doesn't illustrate the issue I am facing. I think it is `@InjectMocks` that is broken.

Comment: You see `@InjectMocks` wont know which `IBroken` to inject. So it is not that it is broken but more the design is flawed.

Comment: @Nkosi oh, maybe I misunderstood. I thought it used the variable name to match up to the constructor parameter name to know which was which. Similar to how Spring injects beans

Comment: No. That is not how `@Mock/@InjectMocks` mocks work in this case.

Comment: @Nkosi well crap, now I need to figure out how to do this since my spring beans use Qualifier to inject these dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@InjectMocks` wont know which `IBroken` to inject. So it is not that it is broken but more the design is flawed.

You would need to explicitly inject the mocks into the subject under test to get the desired behavior.

```
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConstructorInjectionBug {

  @Mock
  private IBroken aBroken;

  @Mock
  private IBroken bBroken;

  private UsesBroken usesBroken;

  @Test
  public void testBrokenConstructorInjection() {
    //Arrange
    usesBroken = new UsesBroken(aBroken, bBroken);
    when(bBroken.getNumber()).thenReturn(2);
    when(aBroken.getNumber()).thenReturn(1);

    //Act & Assert
    assertEquals(2, usesBroken.getbBroken().getNumber());    
    assertEquals(1, usesBroken.getaBroken().getNumber());
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. Unfortunately I have more than just two constructor parameters, but only two are implementations of the same interface. Thanks again for clarifying my understanding of Mockito. Now that I reread the documentation, it seems that if I used setter injection, it wouldn't have been an issue.

Comment: @JoshJ if you have a working solution add it as a self answer. It may also benefit someone in the future with the same problem.

Comment: Yours works. When I get back to that code, this is how I am going to implement it. The setter injection way works, but it isn't valid for my object. My dependencies are final and using setter injection would allow the object to be constructed in an invalid state.